# Trying to convert Arrays to a textfile

Tags: java, arrays, string, text-files

I'm having a problem getting an array to a text file in strings.
My code so far:

```
public class ArrayList 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        int myArray [] = new int [20]; 

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++) { 
                        myArray [i] = (int) (Math.random () * 8);
            System.out.print(myArray[i]);
            String s1 = Arrays.toString(myArray);
            System.out.println(s1);

            s1 = "/Users/EricDkim/Desktop/FileIOTest/pfile.txt";
            File f = new File(s1);
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(f);

            byte value = 0x63; //By adding 0x it reads it as hex
            DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(fileOut);
            //dataoutputstream is used to write primitive java
            //data types (byte, int, char, double) and strings are to a file or a socket
            dataOut.writeByte(value);

            //creates 20 numbers
        }

    }

}
```

How would I use the array that i created to move it to a text file?

Comment: I'm not really a java expertm but shouldn't you open the stream, make your loop, add the data in the file and then close your stream ??

Comment: close data output stream

Comment: @KhalilBhm, you are correct.  Also, shouldn't you have a loop to fill the array, then have a loop to write the array out?  It doesn't make much sense to fill the array as you write it out.  You could have just written out the number.  Plus, your `value` seems to be hard-coded to `0x63`, so it's not writing the array out anyhow.

Comment: do you want to write the integers in the array as bytes or as text?

Comment: thanks for the responses, I need to write this as a text so that I can use that text to convert it into hexadecimal, binary , and decimal values

Comment: @user2984364 see my edited answer, use a delimiter to delimit the numbers, for example a comma `,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about using [DataOutputStream#writeInt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt%28int%29):

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < myArray.length ; i++) { 
    dataOut.writeInt(myArray[i]);
}
```

If you want to write as text then use a [BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html):

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fileOut));
for (int i = 0 ; i < myArray.length ; i++) {
    bw.write(Integer.toString(myArray[i]));
}
bw.close();
```

Don't forget to close the stream/writer.

Try

```
File f = new File(s1);
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(f);
int myArray [] = new int [20];
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fileOut));
for (int i = 0 ; i < myArray.length ; i++) {
    myArray [i] = (int) (Math.random () * 8);
    bw.write(Integer.toString(myArray[i]));
    bw.write(',');
}
bw.close();
```

The content of the file will be

```
0,5,1,3,4,0,0,3,0,6,7,6,4,1,1,6,0,6,7,4,
```

or

```
File f = new File(s1);
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(f);
int myArray [] = new int [20];
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fileOut));
for (int i = 0 ; i < myArray.length ; i++) {
    myArray [i] = (int) (Math.random () * 8);
}
bw.write(Arrays.toString(myArray));
bw.close();
```

The content of the file will be

```
[3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 7, 0, 5, 1, 2, 0, 4, 6, 4]
```

Comment: I followed you comment about using the BufferdWriter and i go the string onto the text file but i keep getting 0's. How would I change the numbers to random numbers, would I change the array?

Comment: Thanks! I got the values I wanted! :D

Answer (score 0):

Declare

```
 File f = new File(s1);
 FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(f);
 DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(fileOut);
```

before the `for` loop and close tour stream at the end of loop like this `dataOut.close();`

For writing the contents as text check this edited code.

```
public class ArrayList {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int myArray[] = new int[20];
    String s1 = "/Users/EricDkim/Desktop/FileIOTest/pfile.txt";
    File f = new File(s1);
    Writer fileOut = new FileWriter(f);
    BufferedWriter dataOut = new BufferedWriter(fileOut);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        myArray[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 8);
        // System.out.print(myArray[i]);
        // String s1 = Arrays.toString(myArray);
        System.out.println(s1);
        byte value = 0x63; // By adding 0x it reads it as hex
        // dataoutputstream is used to write primitive java
        // data types (byte, int, char, double) and strings are to a file or
        // a socket
        fileOut.write(Arrays.toString(myArray) + "\n");
        // creates 20 numbers
    }
    dataOut.close();

}

}
```

Comment: I followed your comment, and I keep getting the file but with nothing in it. The console on java prints out the arrays i want but doesn't print it onto the text file.

Comment: `dataOut.writeByte(value);` it will write the contents of `value` the number of times you loop, in your case it will be repeated 20 times. pass the exact value which you want to write to your file